# Formatting R data.frame - switching observation columns to variables and vice versa?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have data.frame originally derived from a txt-file. It comes in rather inconvenient form where observations are assigned on columns by year. The actual variables I would need as regressors in my analysis are assigned to one column as factors. So I need to do following transformation for this data.frame:

```
         VAR    YEAR.1    YEAR.2    YEAR.3
FIRM.1   VAR.1  FV_11.1   FV_11.2   FV_11.3 
FIRM.1   VAR.2  FV_12.1   FV_12.2   FV_12.3
FIRM.2   VAR.1  FV_21.1   FV_21.2   FV_21.3
FIRM.2   VAR.2  FV_22.1   FV_22.2   FV_22.3
```

where FV_ij.k is observation for firm i variable j at year k. The resulting data.frame would ideally be like this:

```
         YEAR    VAR.1    VAR.2
 FIRM.1  YEAR.1  FV_11.1  FV_12.1
 FIRM.1  YEAR.2  FV_11.2  FV_12.2
 FIRM.1  YEAR.3  FV_11.3  FV_12.3
 FIRM.2  YEAR.1  FV_21.1  FV_22.1
 FIRM.2  YEAR.2  FV_21.2  FV_22.2
 FIRM.2  YEAR.3  FV_21.3  FV_22.3
```

I have an idea how to code this but it is cumbersome. I wonder if there is some package that would do the kind of transformation conveniently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `melt` and `dcast` from the "reshape2" package. But first, here is some sample data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(FIRM = c("FIRM.1", "FIRM.1", "FIRM.2", "FIRM.2"),
    VAR = c("VAR.1", "VAR.2", "VAR.1", "VAR.2"), YEAR.1 = c("FV_11.1",
    "FV_12.1", "FV_21.1", "FV_22.1"), YEAR.2 = c("FV_11.2", "FV_12.2",
    "FV_21.2", "FV_22.2"), YEAR.3 = c("FV_11.3", "FV_12.3", "FV_21.3",
    "FV_22.3")), .Names = c("FIRM", "VAR", "YEAR.1", "YEAR.2", "YEAR.3"),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
mydf
#     FIRM   VAR  YEAR.1  YEAR.2  YEAR.3
# 1 FIRM.1 VAR.1 FV_11.1 FV_11.2 FV_11.3
# 2 FIRM.1 VAR.2 FV_12.1 FV_12.2 FV_12.3
# 3 FIRM.2 VAR.1 FV_21.1 FV_21.2 FV_21.3
# 4 FIRM.2 VAR.2 FV_22.1 FV_22.2 FV_22.3
```

Step 1: Get your data into a long format. Before doing that, though, strip the "VAR." from the "VAR" column

```
library(reshape2)
mydf$VAR <- gsub("VAR.", "", mydf$VAR)
out <- melt(mydf, id.vars=c("FIRM", "VAR"))
```

Step 2: Use `dcast` to get the data into the form you want

```
dcast(out, FIRM + variable ~ VAR)
#     FIRM variable       1       2
# 1 FIRM.1   YEAR.1 FV_11.1 FV_12.1
# 2 FIRM.1   YEAR.2 FV_11.2 FV_12.2
# 3 FIRM.1   YEAR.3 FV_11.3 FV_12.3
# 4 FIRM.2   YEAR.1 FV_21.1 FV_22.1
# 5 FIRM.2   YEAR.2 FV_21.2 FV_22.2
# 6 FIRM.2   YEAR.3 FV_21.3 FV_22.3
```